# React hooks event listener re-added on each render (exhaustive-deps error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am passing a function as a prop and calling that in `useEffect` that triggers a re-render, which is then re-adding a new event listener on each render.

If I remove `incrementCount` from the list of dependencies and leave it as an empty array`[]`, I get the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` linting error, however, it does not trigger after the initial render.

```
function useApp({ incrementCount, count }) {
  console.log(count);

  // this gets triggered on every render
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('add event listener');
    window.addEventListener('click', incrementCount);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', incrementCount);
    };
  }, [incrementCount]);
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function incrementCount() {
    console.log('increment');
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }

  useApp({ incrementCount, count });

  return <div>click</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `useCallback` api from react hooks
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incrementCount = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('increment');
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, [])

  useApp({ incrementCount, count });

  return <div>click</div>;
}
```